# How do I change the background color of the 'rows per page ' selector box when using Bootstrap 4 bootstrap-table?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-table

As standard it is white text on a dark grey background and sits just below the formatted table.

Thanks
Phil

See the image attached.[Section of table showing rows per page selector box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlzPi.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I think I've sorted it...

I've overridden the bootstrap CSS for btn-secondary. I copied the btn-secondary code from the Bootstrap 4 CSS file, edited it with the colors I wanted and added the new style in the html  section after the original Bootstrap 4 CSS link.

It would be good if this color change was definable as an option in bootstrap-table though.

Phil